# Hot reload scss with Vue CLI?

Tags: vue.js

I have started a new Vue project via the CLI. Hot reloading is working fine for all the javascript, but although I can see the scss being compiled, it doesn't reload like the javascript.

I've looked through the docs and searched but don't seem to be able to find the answer. How do I do it?

The `scss` is being imported, and I am making changes to the `scss` files not the `<style lang="scss"></style>`

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the `lang` attribute in your style tags like `<style lang="scss"></style>`?

Comment: Yes, but I don't have styles in them. I am importing a `.scss` file

Comment: Ok then, have you run the command `npm install sass-loader node-sass --save-dev` as shown in the docs [here](http://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/pre-processors.html)?

Comment: I hadn't, simply because I could see sass-loader in my package.json. I have done that but it still doesn't;t reload if I change an css file.

Comment: Could you provide more details about what template/CLI version and configuration are you using? Latest 3.0 CLI appear to be working fine with that you describe. Also: what OS, browser?

Comment: `"@vue/cli-service": "^3.0.0-beta.15",` this is with Firefox developer on Mac OS. Just to clarify. The changes are being made when I edit an `scss` file, but I only see the changes when I refresh the page. I was hoping it would hot load like the `js` does

Comment: Hot reloading `.scss` works for me (no refresh needed). I'm using the latest `vue-cli` version though (`3.0.0-rc.3`). Chrome 67 on macOS High Sierra. It worked two different ways (`import './styles.scss'` and `<style lang="scss" src="./styles.scss">`).

Comment: Just tried Firefox Developer Edition `62.0b4` on macOS, and hot reloading `.scss` works, so I'm guessing it's your `vue-cli` version.

Comment: I only downloaded `vie-cli` yesterday though, but I have beta15? I would have thought it would give me the latest stable version. I'll go and update and try again

Comment: It turns out it is working. I was using `body { background-color: red; }` in my main `app.scss` file as a test and changing the colours and nothing would be updated. However, the `@import` files in the `app.scss`, if they are changed, it hot reloads. I can even change `font-size` within `app.scss` and I see the change, but for some reason `background-colour` only changes when the page is refreshed.